# Authentication error with Sharepoint API Python Office365 - KeyError: 'FedAuth'

Tags: python, office365

I am trying to connect to Sharepoint using the following code and get KeyError: 'FedAuth'.
My goal is to get access to online Sharepoint through the API to read some xlsx files.
I tried all the open/close topic that I found here, but I get the same error every time

```
#import all the libraries
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files import file

#target url taken from sharepoint and credentials
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print("Authentication successful")
```

```
An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS90023: Invalid STS request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tacohen/ws-test/test/software-repo/devops/icetest/Office365-script.py", line 28, in <module>
    if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/office365/runtime/auth/authentication_context.py", line 47, in acquire_token_for_user
    if not self.provider.acquire_token():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/office365/runtime/auth/providers/saml_token_provider.py", line 68, in acquire_token
    return self._acquire_authentication_cookie(token, user_realm.IsFederated)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/office365/runtime/auth/providers/saml_token_provider.py", line 232, in _acquire_authentication_cookie
    self._auth_cookies[name] = cookies[name]
KeyError: 'FedAuth'
```

Comment: Hi someone can help ?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://superuser.com/a/1478900

Comment: I am running into same error. Was wondering if you found any solution for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a detailed solution: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/191#issuecomment-709398379